# How can i use wp_get_image_editor for image resizing

Tags: images

I search a lot that how can i re-size images that upload with meta field but i get nothing instead of `wp_get_image_editor`. I read from codex about it but nothing helpful so I search about this function and found these links

http://bhoover.com/wp_image_editor-wordpress-image-editing-tutorial/

http://wpunknown.com/wp_image_editor/

but it also not usefull for me.

I tried scripts from first link. First i upload an image from media and then create a page template and write this code in my template in while loop:

```
if(have_posts()) :
    while(have_posts()) :
        the_post();

        the_title();

        // wp editor image script
        $testing_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');

        $img = wp_get_image_editor( $testing_img_src[0] );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $img ) ) {
            $img->resize( 500, NULL, false );
            $img->set_quality( 100 );
            $img->stream();
        }

    endwhile;
```

When i fresh the page it gives me this kind of crap:

```
����JFIF��,��gf8�R�����;�8'���Z�v� F��`q�q� <+�g�51N��`NO���2�Bo���Jֵ��>����o3����M]�(��]�[�u���^핺��_�#;U�,OLs��$�� �F �+XΪ�|�rx�v���p |�&�����s�u<H��a��=r�}�X��dR�� ������07`qھk�r� ���$����tvw�l����朴�B�i]�-R��}.�N)6���>ҵ�,na��G9-���8�#��Kik6 �$y>�w�� �N��~=��1�y8!�ʂ:��v��1����V(U%r6�e��Ns��'�7t �x��1�yF2�I]Y���ˢ~�����5��Z�T��m5&����u+�^��^�} 7���\ЎGL�����`�� ��jm�Q�s� gn���#8�p���Um#�v�rQZu�d����N@� `�3�s^�a�:�����2G�<�A��ǌz�'�fx+Ƣ����;��>�.�6֎��1Y�:sS�MYI[E�v\�����j��5τk)>\!K���덤�@�둞�9�|)����u9 ��\c9��v<�_�>�y���㿠����98��_M�S�FK��� ��`�!H#�������IENSi+ZZ��o��V������=���sx��MNWmӌcZO�i�=��馺/��� �Zk�h���#pʶHc�J����1Y?oլ���]F2�(�BN�1�Q�A�2 �����:�IKt,s� 9(��m�n�^;�|�Us�������9$� �3���@?k���"1X�T�t�������o}ZX�G�>��U2�UJmk9;+-4�\R��QM�eu��ŏ��9[�����`���O�9� �$q�[kZu�+�N����O\���� {����f��@�pH%Hϧ$����$�~�c���L�B�7#��gvO�k�)b�{2Iӯ R��rV�u�M+lܞ������4�㍲5(���S�q����f�ҋ~�W~���[�R++�J��۹O^:�|����`֟��\�����$�`7:���s۟e � ����)$E�X�H$��(U>�v'Z���[��H��q�~��T�G}�B�&� S����֋I�W 4��N-Żi�O[�O��ή�Y������Fp��qJ|��V���w�m�j�5[��|��!Nv��� ����>�����,��*q��w)1�8�U��y�]mJ�8�bX��$��O%�����K�$�������9���FO�f|��̱XJ7j�M=5��o9h�����`�2r�bR��V�Y9��n�'e��)s$���>5�~�F��*rQJ`�@�d�9 s���;�I*:1;Y�}�8�@��~�d�i�Hط�)�����8=�Y7���!�c>�YT|��c��20r3�+���^�y��q�䞼�릯f�k6��.�����pxz괕���8�YFq�KmaukJ��?���V�yɀ� ��c��\pH=����'Z�^��U`@#~Cd��N�;���>��~9I0 ��'v8�$�����כj��`ge����rp0xۏ�q���q��{�z��s�[]ӓ��T��dӳv�}U���{8~ ���X������V��)FQk�����e�O��[k�����3�������5�Ť�q����Q���$Ԍ����>j���ʥC�v�f@;JF@Rs�A�y�KA`q�����|W�%e�#q���^>� ����ONģk$�7��i.���m�~���t�Ғ��<�����wvwm[僫�&�2�$��g�gh���ӷ`���R��:b�@�RX+)~FyNppæ �F?NY��C��@w`��2G^ �9��<�N���/Ԝ������8$��<�� �_9��̯u[N�j��M����w���{��$�҇���R�mG����V���[Kk�$��g�2�D���n#v N�nRޘ) ���<�1̖�|���dF�����A�a�}�xL��D/�w�)w(<B_rO���4��0�!l��9�9��H����f���ܝ�ݚZ���}l읬���s��\�u^*�7k5{Yr�]�[;�d���ic�գȡ��t�b0����4W��| �\8��TN�Q�|o�:gМ�E|��n7v�G������S��[y�|B�JXuk���ݾ�|��~W������eN��pI�2p�A�y8Ÿ��$����5<jM�袢�3i�Y��>Vm:��$y8�z�`{���7m5k�"���B1���1��x�������xV�l����nI�9����s�����\� ���q�В@�{�./�NΣJ���j�I�����|�g��W���UU��ۊ��i%u������_��|n��9�O�q��20���Ѵ�i�!6ʀ��<��lr�v�OB8[���� ���?־�o1�I$+G$���F '$� 0���֘�|�@BH*��� �a�6?H��L�P�S �8���d��+#Q�{�_���lp@�����GO�zc�'�r�/�pR����dՒz5���]U�}�WG�Q�tʳHԞ� �+�8��V|�N�_���H���>������y9 0�$,��F���.Y��U�I�#vOB}��{��~[�dx! ��( ��H#�s�pG`>Q�����F�sE�c�8����{�,q�+����� ��V��*KI���]7ItIj�Vg���s�S��N-6��<*Z��W��vmEݞ��x�O�Dt9#��������8�� ���ep�R[� dH�G98�prB�·����Љ�#d�� �8<����Cm��i,�h@@9�F <�r@��@�'���!�_�8��5eg'^�umY�Y�|���!�?�'/k��(A��)�OM�v�^��d�W�Gߥ,��)�������ッ���xr)�h����;�����3؃��z'Ư,�]�NH;�A��K:��kۼ;�oL�T t�w_�c�I ���Pk�ܫ��||aɊ�$���I_f����Y����q�?���ƥ)F\��yӳJ�RM'�z(�v3�z�����v��^:q�`t$� UY5{i�Pz�OA?78�3���w_�t���G;�猯�\����/c��~��2O�H�Br8� �������p��q����ee���OG��F�}���4� �E)^5h����%is-�ꬵj�S�4ψ:�ˉ� >z�����q�zz���=^٘��\��s�8 )$���������j�S�R~�`�L��~E]xg[��x��6rp ���r:>���-��)I�B��,8#���o�5�s<��y� �+I�k�N�2[�%n�a�iAr>WN+N��������c���Uӯv�x�89[+���'�x$��kO���9����^�b���Ɵ�K�r�r <�K�y�c�\ӼW��F�M�2�p'9��N�c95������R ��Q����kU}ԗe��r~����J,����u��Oe��}U�5]h��IE���ns�_��T�`@�*�>1���3L��K��z�mـ � ����G�a��#6#9��c�����C�ޓ�F�"��0>U9��;�
```

I also tried to add hard coded image path like:

```
//$testing_img_src = ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/2015/06/colorful-background-31.jpg';
```

but it gives me same result. So please help me that how can i use `wp_get_image_editor()` so that my image resized or crop OR there is an other way for this.

***NOTE:*** I don't want to use `add_image_size()`

Comment: if you stream your image as jpg you might get a hard time if you echo it with text/html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A possible solution:

**Goal:** Don't use `add_image_size()` to show a custom sized image.

If you calculate the image without saving it, all requests will sum up to a huge page load due to repeated unnecessary processing time. So caching or saving the results should be an additional goal.

Add a **image-processor.php** in your template/plugin:

```
//Load your WordPress enviroment
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$path = substr($path, 0, stripos($path, "wp-content") );
require( $path . "wp-load.php");

//TODO: filter and handle your $_GET params
$post_id = absint($_GET['post_id']);

$testing_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url(
    get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'
);

if (!$testing_img_url)
    $testing_img_url = 'http://domain.tld/path/to/defaul-image.jpg';

$img = wp_get_image_editor( $testing_img_url );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $img ) ) {
    header('Content-type:'.finfo_file ($testing_img_url));
    $img->resize( 500, NULL, false );
    $img->set_quality( 100 );
    $img->stream();
}
```

You can display the image in a loop now like this:

**Template**:

```
<img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri()?>/image-processor.php?post_id=<?= get_the_ID()?>">
```

**Plugin**:

```
<img src="<?= plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)?>image-processor.php?post_id=<?= get_the_ID()?>">
```

### Possible improvements:

- Caching/saving the processed images.
- Better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I have used wp_get_image_editor for Instagram images resizing. You can use it in similar fashion for posts or any